# random slope to vary across different grouping variables in mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a mixed model of the form

```
lmer(y_log ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + I(x4^2) + x5 + I(x5^2) + (1 + x1|group1/group2),
     data = lmerDat, na.action = 'na.fail', REML = F,
     lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e6))))
```

If I want to specify a model of the form where `x1` varies across group1 and group2 while the remaining variables varies only across group1, is the following specification correct?

```
lmer(y_log ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + I(x4^2) + x5 + I(x5^2) + 
     (1 + x1|group1/group2) + 
     (x2 + x3 + x4 + I(x4^2) + x5 + I(x^5)|group1),
     data = lmerDat, na.action = 'na.fail', REML = F,
     lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e6))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that random effects are used to model correlations. A model that contains the term `(1 | group1 / group2)` will include a random intercept for `group1` and a nested random intercept for `group2`. This would specify that measurements of `y_log` in the same level of `group1` will be correlated, and the measurements of `y_log` in the same level of `group2` within `group1` will be even more correlated.

When you include the term `(x1 | group1 / group2)` you further postulate that the correlations in the `y_log` measurements become smaller as the difference in the corresponding `x1` values becomes larger. Including two random slopes, i.e., `(x1 + x2 | group1 / group2)` will say something along the same lines.

Taking the above points into account, the random-effects structure you have postulated seems rather complicated. Are you certain that this is what you want to assume for your data?